# Can not scroll menu - content "behind" the menu scrolls

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I created a small menu based on tailwindcss. It works fine, but there's one thing: If this menu is shown on mobile devices, the user scrolls the content of the page that is "behind" the menu. So some menu items can not be shown.

I created a codepen to demonstrate this:

https://codepen.io/spqrinc/pen/RwPBBKq

This is how I defined the fixed menu position:

```
<div class="bg-gray-500 md:flex md:justify-between md:items-center md:px-4 md:py-3  w-full z-50 top-0 fixed">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between px-4 py-3 md:p-0">
            [...]
        </div>
</div>
```

I also created a gif to show what I mean - just click the image to start the gif's animation:

[image: Example]

I am not sure, why this is happening. I guess I messed something up with the fixed position. So I am very thankful for your help - my goal is to have a menu that's scrollable and fixed on mobile devices.

Comment: just remove the class `fixed` from the div just below the header, but you will lose the header behavior

Comment: Hi. In this case the menu would not be sticky on mobile, but this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: if you reduce the header size you will see that the content is scrolling and the header is fixed, I think that you ave the correct behavior but it's just layout issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two potential solutions, one involving JavaScript, and the other not.

I would recommend the solution without JavaScript and later on, enhance it with JavaScript.

The first solution would be to use **sticky** position on the navbar instead of fixed.

I have created a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/avcajaraville/pen/wvaYzLJ) to demonstrate it (resize for "mobile layout").

Good part is that works out of the box, only a class change (sticky class):

```
<div class="bg-gray-500 md:flex md:justify-between md:items-center md:px-4 md:py-3  w-full z-50 top-0 sticky">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between px-4 py-3 md:p-0">
    [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

The negative one is that the menu isn't fixed.

For that, we will need a bit of JavaScript (not added to the codepen).

Basically we need to prevent overflow on the "body" (in your case, not the actual body, but the area that holds the content) and to add a bottom property to delimitate the navbar height in addition to an `overflow-y: scroll;` on the navigation.

I created [this codepen](https://codepen.io/avcajaraville/pen/XWbxNry) to illustrate it. Again, view it in "mobile layout".

These are the classes involved:

```
.header-wrapper {
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I added this class to the first child of the `header` element:

```
<header class="lg:mb-20">
    <div class="header-wrapper bg-gray-500 md:flex md:justify-between md:items-center md:px-4 md:py-3  w-full z-50 top-0 fixed">
  </div>
</header>
```

You need to add this class only to mobile and only when the menu is open.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have `fixed` applied there. For small screens, you can use something like `absolute`, it depends of what you want to achieve.

But `absolute md:fixed` should fix it. From there, you can tweak it as you want.

Comment: So there's no possibility to have it fixed on mobile too without the scrolling-issue?

Comment: Of course it is possible. As far as I see, you want to have full width top fixed menu on desktop screen and then dropdown on mobile. To achieve that, you will need to have separate `div` floating with menu items for mobile screens. Top menu can stay the same, but on mobile screens, hide all of menu items. For the mobile screens, show that `div` with menu items. See this tutorial here how to do it: https://tailwindcss.com/course/styling-the-basic-dropdown-elements/ that video and next 4 videos.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your menu is full-screen, there's a trick you can do. Short story: make your body position fixed, then make your menu in relative position so you can benefit natural scrolling.

Asuming you have your entire user interface wrapped inside a container (a simple `div` should suffice) and not laying directly inside your `body`, the following should apply.

When you open the menu, do the following:

```js
const uiContainer = document.getElementById('ui-container');
uiContainer.style.position = 'fixed';

/* Store scrollX and scrollY in some safe location.
 * You will need them when the menu closes. */
uiContainer.style.top = `-${window.scrollY}px`;
uiContainer.style.left = `-${window.scrollX}px`;
uiContainer.style.width = '100%';
```

When the menu is closing, do the following:

```
uiContainer.style.position = null;
uiContainer.style.width = null;
uiContainer.style.top = null;
uiContainer.style.left = null;

window.scrollTo(savedScrollX, savedScrollY);
```

Then you can add your menu as a child to the `body` and have it styled with `position: relative` and scrolling will be naturally handled by any browser.

HTH